# Url routing - infinite url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

I use asp.net mvc3 and I want to write route that has no end..
I mean something like that:

```
www.site.com/Cameras/{id}={string}/{id}={string}/{id}={string}/{id}={string}.....
```

where the id represent a filter id and the string represent a value of that filter..
I have many types of filters and in the future I want to be able to add more without any dependence..
How should this kind of route should look? And how do I start to deal these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write a catchall route and then interpret it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Cameras", "cameras/{*url}",
      new { controller = "Cameras", action = "Index" }
  );



public ActionResult Index(string url)
{
     var ids = url.split('/');
     // now do what you need with the ids

}
```

You should use urls like this:

/cameras/id1/id2/id3/id4

Comment: I'm not sure if the question did mean this but what if you don't have an id1 or you only have an id6 or something? I've not really used any of this sort of thing myself but it strikes me as something that you'd want to do if you wanted to add parameters abritrarily - remove them too...

Comment: I agree that it's not necessarliy the best option but if you want a non ending list of ids that you can then interpret this would be the way.

Comment: I guess you can just make the urls something like `/cameras/name=bob/paramX=28/` etc. Or if `=` is a special character then just some other chosen thing. Is using a querystring frowned on in mvc3 or would that actually be the better way of doing arbitrary urls like this? Sorry if the question is silly but I don't use MVC and am trying to absorb knowledge on it like this :)

Comment: Is there any other "smarter" solution?